# How to filter active users from the following code

Tags: user, opportunity-teams

```
    if(sobj!=null)
    {
        query   = 'select Id';
        //Gets the details of the sobject
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobjResult = sobj.getsObjectType().getDescribe();

        //Add field names to query
        for(Schema.SObjectField field : sobjResult.fields.getMap().values()) 
        {
            if(field.getDescribe().isAccessible() && field.getDescribe().isCreateable() && !field.getDescribe().isUnique() &&
            !field.getDescribe().isAutoNumber() && !field.getDescribe().isCalculated()) 
            {
                query += ',' + field.getDescribe().getName();
            }
        }        
        query+= ' from '+ sobjResult.getName();
        system.debug('-------Query-----'+query);
    }
    return query;
  }
```

> ERROR: owner or user is inactive. insert failure

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter out in the where clause objects that have an inactive User as an owner in this dynamically created query?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Filter only active users. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply append your query with an additional `where` part that filters out inactive owners as following:

```
WHERE Owner.isactive = true
```